# Can I create a cross platform application with HTML5?

Tags: windows, html, ios, cross-platform, websocket

I have to target Windows, MacOS, iOS and Android. My plan was to create separate applications for each platform.

However, I am now considering making an HTML5 website (that has different presentations based upon the device being used).

I can create a wrapper for each platform. Windows can include a Webkit control, iOS will have Safari, etc...

The wrapper will load the HTML5 pages into the browser and negotiate input/output for persistance. I can use [WebSockets](http://websockets.org) for communication with the outside world (ie. my server).

What am I missing here? What else would be required and what would be the obstacles I would have to overcome?

Comment: I'd say it depends on what kind of application it is and how native it needs to "feel" to the platform. Web apps are great for web app suited apps, they may not be a great replacement for desktop/native apps.

Comment: I could achieve the functionality and the look and feel I wanted, with HTML5 (probably easier than I could with Objective-C actually). However, I would want to package it as an application (a wrapper around the website) and my question is asking if this is possible or problematic.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but websites *never* feel as native as native apps. Just my ¥1.67 though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Best option for making cross platform applications is PhoneGap.

In PhoneGap you write HTML5 and JS code, it provides access of native APIs using JS code and allows you to compile your application and submit to different App stores.

http://www.phonegap.com